# Python Pathing Issue

Tags: python, path

So i don't have any code to show because this isn't a code issue.
I have my pathing for Python set to this:
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310;C:\Users\stone\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts
but in command prompt it still paths:
C:\Users\USERNAME>
and delivers a "errno 2" error whenever I try to run a file. The only way I have gotten files to actually launch is to move the .py folders to the username folder.

Comment: PYTHONPATH only works for when you're trying to import things _inside_ the python interpreter. In the command prompt, it is still using the path for the terminal, which presumably doesn't include the folder your .py file is in. When you move the .py file to the current working directory (`C:\Users\USERNAME`), the .py file is right there so the terminal finds it and sends it to the python interpreter to run. If you want to run `python myscript.py` from any working directory, you're going to have to add it to your _system_ path (or the path for the terminal you're running it in)

Answer (score -1):

I had this issue before in the past and what I ended up doing is reinstalling python and making sure to hit the "add to path" option. Sorry I don't have a better way but that is what worked for me.

Comment: I tried this but I couldn't get it to work. Thank you though